# Where to buy a used bicycle in Germany?

Tags: used-bike, germany

I would like to buy a cheap bicycle in Germany. Is there any place to search for a used bicycle (like a market or an internet site)? I don't speak German so places where people might speak English are preferred.

Comment: where in Germany? what do you call cheap?

Comment: Mannheim. And cheep would mean not new in this case. Would be really nice to know about a place where people would sell their bicycles knowing they are nor stolen or broken.

Comment: I was hesitant to close this, as we have [a thread open in meta right now](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/476/regional-questions-revisited-should-we-have-them) to debate regional questions in general. However, this question is attracting short answers that are unlikely to be of use to anyone else. (This decision is by no means final, please be patient.)

Comment: @Neil It's not just whether answers are useful to anyone else: if the answers are useful to the OP, I think that's sufficient justification for the question.

Comment: With a small effort, this could definitely be a useful question: suggesting what might be different about the second hand market in Germany, for example. I agree with @Neil Fein in as much as being wary - after all there are 200+ countries in the world and we don't need a question of this type for each of them.

Comment: Why not. I certainly was looking for an answer for this question. There might be others as well. Apparently education and work conditions in Germany are pretty good so many young people move here. There are also quite a few foreign military forces who I'm not sure will be interested in used bikes but who knows...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

eBay:

http://kleinanzeigen.ebay.de/anzeigen/s-fahrrad/k0

Open in Chrome and use 'Google Translate'. 'Fahrrad' is your keyword.

P.S. Most German people speak better English than some English people do!!!

Comment: Oh. That's cool. Never heard about ebay classifieds. I'm not sure that most German people speak English well but many do speak ok.

Answer (score 2):

Technically not in Germany but 2 kilometers from the border, there is this market:

http://www.velostation-strasbourg.org/bourse-aux-velos.html

It is run by a non-profit. A few hundred bicycles at each event, you can put your own for sale too. I bought one of my bicycles there.

Comment: That's circa 100km from Mannheim.

Comment: and how it's not October yet so it's still more than a month. But it's nice to know anyway

Comment: @Sergej: Whoa, I am so confused with the calendar... thanks!